# Rigged mesh rendering differently to viewport (AFTER EDIT)

Tags: rendering, mesh, rigging, edit-mode

I have a rigged character with a sort of "belt strap" across his body. This has been rigged and weighted so it moves correctly with his poses. In the pose I'm wanting to render his belt strap phases through his tunic.

I've edited the mesh (with "on cage" & "edit mode" ticked in the Armature Modifier tab) so that the belt strap and tunic align correctly. Unfortunately, the render does NOT reflect this change, and renders without the new edit.

Looking for solutions!

Image 1 (Viewport - with edit)

Image 2 (Render - with edit but not showing edit)

[image: Viewport]

[image: Render]

Comment: Note, I cannot " Object -> Apply -> Visual Geometry to Mesh "' as I plan on animating the dude, not just getting this 1 render. Nor does this actually work.

Comment: hello, could you please just share the belt + cloth? https://pasteall.org/blend/